# How to add macro's definition in cmake?

Tags: boost, mongodb, cmake

I am using Mongodb client and Boost in my C++ application. Because the Mongodb client is still using Boost old filesystem and my C++ application is using filesystem version 3 from boost 1.47.0, they conflict.

I found a way to solve this compilation problem, namely add a macro definition before all include statements for the header files from Boost in my cpp files:

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2
```

But I want to know how to put the above macro's definition into my CMake project files.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Take a look at [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html), which will add your definitions to your compiler command line, e.g. `-D` with gcc, or `/D` with MSVC. Try something like:

```
add_definitions( -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 )
```

In your case, I would definitely go with the `add_definition` method, but an alternative may to take a look at [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html). Then you can create a header-file template, which will be filled with cmake-values and include this in your source files. This can be useful if you have many, many configurable parameters which are determined by CMake.

Comment: This helped compile a C++0x project that wouldn't otherwise compile. You Sir, is Awesome! :D

Comment: When the value is another macro, which has double underscore, like `__FUNCTION__`, for example, what should the process be?

Comment: Is there anywhere to specify these in `ccmake`?

Comment: It looks this solution is not portable. If I use a tird-party compiler it may not recognize the `-D` option.

Comment: @nowox Since cmake 3.12 there's the cleaner [`add_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions) available.

Answer (score 7):

Since CMake 3 there's [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) to set defines for specific target only.

Example:

```
target_compile_definitions(your_target_name PUBLIC BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2)
```