# Turn off Eigen Alignment in the PCL build

Tags: c++, eigen, memory-alignment, point-cloud-library, qnx

So I have an issue where Eigen Alignment causes serious issues with the operating system I use, QNX. Basically the OS cannot deal with the memory that way and causes very interesting seg faults. See my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190767/identify-variable-causing-memory-error).

Any way, for this reason I wish to disable the Eigen Alignment used in PCL before I build it. 
I have a couple of ideas about how i might do this.

**EIGEN INCLUDE FILES IN PCL**

So PCL has the structure for most of its modules like this (this is an example of the features module):

```
pcl/include/pcl/features/
```

and in this folder there exists a eigen.h file. This seems to be where the `eigen` libraries are included from. I could put the macro `#define EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` in each of these. Of course this is many many files in PCL, as there are a lot of modules. One potential problem with this is that the modules then have things like `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` in a bunch of their include files. Is this going to combat my efforts to turn it off? Also there are these standrard eigen includes but other files also include Eigen directly, what should i do about those?

**TURN OFF EIGEN ALIGNMENT IN EIGEN**

Is there a way to do this? I have had a quick search and it doesn't seem like there is a way to install the header only library with this turned off?

**OTHER IDEAS**

I would be happy to hear any other suggestions with how to deal with this?

Comment: Not following you very well.  you define `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` before including any eigen file and the `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` propagates to all headers.

Comment: @Anycorn I am defining `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` in the `eigen.h` include files used by PCL to distribute the eigen includes. The problem with this is that there are other includes as well and the references to `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` make me nervous. Does that make sense?

Comment: PCL uses CMake, right?  take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770834/how-to-add-macros-definition-in-cmake

Comment: @Anycorn, had a look, you think that will filter down and solve my problem? I will give it a go. You should add it as an answer.

Comment: Unless PCL people did something bizarre, the definitions added in CMake should be visible across all compilation units

Comment: @Anycorn Well CMake worked and it is building now. You should add this as an answer and once i have tested it I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by @Anycorn is outdated: starting from 3.3 (or 3.2 ?), this macro is deprecated, see [this bug report](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1348), and [the current state](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) of the page describing the various macros.

You should now use `EIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=0`.

Answer (score 2):

PCL uses CMake as a build system.

You can add `add_definitions(-DEIGEN_DONT_ALIGN)` line in CMakeLists.txt to achieve what you want

Comment: Hey Anycorn, I implemented this but I am getting segfaults which i think are related to Eigen alignment. There exists in the pcl source code `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW`, does this overide the setting of `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN`?

Comment: That macro is for making sure that structures containing Eigen objects are alignment.  Try to disable vectorization, `-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` - it should be off already but ...

Comment: @Ben secondly, are you crosscompiling for QNX or natively?

Comment: Compiling natively. I will try that as well.